# Getting NullPointerException with SmbFileInputStream

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jcifs

Trying to modify excel which is in another machine. Passing IP address, username, password and file path to access and modify file, but getting NullPointerException at `new SmbFileInputStream(sFile)`. What is the reason for this?

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domin", "username", "password");
                String path = "smb:\\\\<IPaddress>\\C$\\<FolderName>\\File%20-%20Input.xlsx";
                SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);



                try {
                    SmbFileInputStream inputStream = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile);
                    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

                    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum(),i=0;
                    Cell cell;
                    for(ForemostReservedDataDO obj : unsavedRecords){
                        i++;
                        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount+i);
                        cell = row.createCell(0);
                        cell.setCellValue(obj.getPolicyNum());
                        cell = row.createCell(1);
                        cell.setCellValue("Recreational Value");
                    }
                    inputStream.close();

                    SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
                    workbook.write(sfos);
                    workbook.close();
                    sfos.close();

                } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Full Stack

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/Foremost] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jcifs.smb.ServerMessageBlock.writeString(ServerMessageBlock.java:213)
    at jcifs.smb.ServerMessageBlock.writeString(ServerMessageBlock.java:202)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbComNTCreateAndX.writeBytesWireFormat(SmbComNTCreateAndX.java:170)
    at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.writeAndXWireFormat(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:101)
    at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.encode(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:65)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doSend(SmbTransport.java:439)
    at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.sendrecv(Transport.java:67)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:655)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:989)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:73)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:65)
    at com.Foremost.Controllers.DataDownController.saveReservedData(DataDownController.java:217)
```

Comment: Please add the full Stacktrace of the NPE to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the Stacktrace. Which version of JCIFS are you using?

Comment: jcifs version is 1.3.17

Comment: Thanks (you should add that to the question). That is a **very** old version, you should upgrade to latest version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codelibs/jcifs/2.1.3 (note: new groupId)

Comment: Apology, next time definitely will mention version. Can you provide me any sample code with latest version (2.1.3) as per my requirement. which i written that's getting compile errors with latest jar (because those are deprecated methods)

Comment: Added example code to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JCIFS version seems to be outdated and not compatible with the remote system. Upgrade to latest JCIFS (current version: 2.1.3, https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs) or to jcifs-ng (https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng), from which the linked JCIFS is now a fork of.

Here is some example code on how to use jcifs-ng for reading a file via SMB:

```
String fileUrl = "smb://netserver/some/path/to/file.xls";

Properties cifsProps = new Properties();
cifsProps.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "my.domain.int");
cifsProps.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", USER_NAME);
cifsProps.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", PASSWORD);

Configuration config = new PropertyConfiguration(cifsProps);
BaseContext context = new BaseContext(config);
SmbResource resource = context.get(fileUrl);

if (!(resource instanceof SmbFile)) {
    throw new CIFSException("File URL does not point to a file on a network share");
}

try (InputStream in = ((SmbFile) resource).getInputStream()) {
    // TODO read from in
} finally {
    context.close();
}
```

For writing a file, well, I think you will be able to figure that out :-)

Comment: great, thanks @Florian. have small problem, mine is jdk1.7 I need JDK 1.8 for JCIFS 2.1.3. i'm trying to upgrade my project. anyway thank you very much. once i done i will give voting for your answer.

Comment: I think they removed 1.7 support just recently. Perhaps you could e.g. use jcifs-ng 2.0.5, that should work fine with 1.7 and still be recent enough.

Comment: Yes i tried with jcifs-ng 2.0.5 getting jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Access is denied. but with the same user i'm able open and modify directly. What would be the wrong ?

Comment: getting access denied, create new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387310/jcifs-smb-smbauthexception-access-is-denied

Comment: Have one doubt, is it mandatory to share the folder which i want to access? can not we connect with out share?

Comment: If you can connect via Windows Explorer or via Linux CIFS methods, you should be able to connect - with same credentials - via JCIFS as well. Please consider that you may have to specify a domain name, as in my example - which may be WORKGROUP in simple networks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the problem is that your `sFile` object is `null`.

Check the path of file you are providing.

Comment: Well, that also was my first thought, but as `sFile = new SmbFile(...)`, if there is no crucial line of code removed, it cannot be `null` if that line succeeds.

Comment: No, if the path is incorrect that in that case there is a possibility that sFile will be null. Can you put a debugger and check whether sFile is null or not?

Comment: I am not the OP. And no, sFile can **not** be null if it is initialized with a `new SmbFile(...)`. No Java reference can ever be null after initialized with a new instance of a class, unless the constructor call fails with an exception (which would then cause an exception on another line than the OP reported).

Comment: sFile is not null checked in debug.